# How can i delete a document in firebase which the user has created while using their uid code. Dart code 'Flutter'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is where I write the data to my Firebase,

```
class userContent {
  final String uid;
  userContent({this.uid});

  bool isLoggedIn() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser() != null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<Void> addData(propertyData) async {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('userContent')
          .document('posts')
          .collection('postCollection')
          .add(propertyData)
          .catchError((e) {
        print(e);
      });
    } else {
      print('You need to be logged in');
    }
  }

  getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection('userContent')
        .document('posts')
        .collection('postCollection')
        .snapshots();
  }

  updateData(selectedDoc, newValues) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('userContent')
        .document('posts')
        .collection('postCollection')
        .document(selectedDoc)
        .updateData(newValues)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  deleteData(docId) {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('userContent')
        .document('posts')
        .collection('postCollection')
        .document(docId)
        .delete()
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  UserContent _userDataFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserContent(
      uid: uid,
    );
  }

  Stream<UserContent> get userDataStream {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('userContent')
        .document('posts')
        .collection(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

this is what I use to show the dialog where users can add a new property to my Firebase storage,

```
Future<bool> addDialog(BuildContext context) async {
final user = Provider.of<User>(context);

return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Add Data', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter the property\'s title' : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter property title'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.propertyTitle = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter the property\'s address' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter the property\'s Address'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.propetyAddress = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter the property\'s postcode' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Enter the property\'s potcode'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.propertyPostcode = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter the property\'s price' : null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter a price'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.propertyPrice = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                      ? 'Enter sales type \'(For Sale or To rent)\''
                      : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter selling type'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.sellingType = value;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter a description' : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Detail Description'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.moreDetails = value;
                  },
                ),
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: numberOfbaths ?? '1',
                  items: bathrooms.map((bathrooms) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: bathrooms,
                      child: Text('$bathrooms bathrooms'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    this.numberOfbaths = value;
                  },
                ),
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: numberOfbedrooms ?? '1',
                  items: bedrooms.map((bedrooms) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: bedrooms,
                      child: Text('$bedrooms bedrooms'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    this.numberOfbedrooms = value;
                  },
                ),
                DropdownButtonFormField(
                  value: numberOflivingrooms ?? '1',
                  items: livingrooms.map((livingrooms) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: livingrooms,
                      child: Text('$livingrooms livingrooms'),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (String value) {
                    this.numberOflivingrooms = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter energy costs per month' : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Energy Costs per month'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.energyPermonth = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter tax costs per month' : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Tax Costs per month'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.taxPermonth = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (val) =>
                      val.isEmpty ? 'Enter water costs per month' : null,
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: 'Water Costs per month'),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.waterPermonth = value;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Add'),
            textColor: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                userContent(uid: user.uid).addData({
                  'uid': user.uid,
                  'Property Title': this.propertyTitle,
                  'Seller Name': this.sellerName,
                  'Property Address': this.propetyAddress,
                  'Property Postcode': this.propertyPostcode,
                  'Property Price': this.propertyPrice,
                  'Selling Type': this.sellingType,
                  'more Details': this.moreDetails,
                  'Number of Bathrooms': this.numberOfbaths,
                  'Number of Bedrooms': this.numberOfbedrooms,
                  'Number of Livingrooms': this.numberOflivingrooms,
                  'Energy per Month': this.energyPermonth,
                  'Tax per Month': this.taxPermonth,
                  'Water per Month': this.waterPermonth,
                }).catchError((e) {
                  print(e);
                  print(user.uid);
                });
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      );
    });
```

}

I have figured out how to include the uid but I don't know how to use it for deleting a document.
I have seen lots of different suggestions on stack flow but I struggle in my case.
Please, could someone help me and others who would run into the same kind of issue then you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Don't forget to make it an sync

```
    await Firestore.instance 
.collection('userContent') .
document('posts') .
collection('postCollection') .
document(uid) .delete()
```